# Undefined Index at Login (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting two annoying undefined index lines. I was trying to fix these.

*Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\lynnletbo\diarypanel\login.php on line 4
Notice: Undefined index: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\lynnletbo\diarypanel\login.php on line 5*

**login.php**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method = "post" action = "login.php">
    <input type = "text" name = "user" placeholder = "Username" />
    <input type = "password" name = "pass" placeholder = "Password" />
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Login" />
    </form>
</body>
```

The above code is a form where I can login.

Here is the following code that I use to check from Database and login.

```
<?php
require('../db_connect.php');
session_start();
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
if(isset($_POST) && $username != '' && $password != '') {
    $sql = $database->prepare("SELECT `user_id`, `user_password` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = ?");
    $sql->execute(array($username));
    if ($row = $sql->fetch()){
        $_SESSION['username'] = true;
    }
    else {
        echo "Can't login";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple, just check whether these indices exists in POST before processing the form.

Normally, `$_POST` values are unpopulated on initial load, so assigning them on load will spew that undefined index error.

```
<?php

require '../db_connect.php';
session_start();

if (!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {

    // then continue
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $sql = $database->prepare("SELECT `user_id`, `user_password` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = ?");
    $sql->execute(array($username));
    if ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = true;
        // handle password matching here
    }
    else {
        echo "Can't login";
    }


}

?>
```

There are some intricacies that goes into this. If you'd like to know those, I suggest visit [deceze's article](http://kunststube.net/isset/) to know more.

Comment: Don't we have enough dupes for this?

Comment: Thanks. I should've used empty function before defining a new post variable.

Comment: @Rizier123 actually i was going to rescind this, but i guess im bored having to find the canonical. i always forget to use our golden hammer lol :D

Comment: @lynnletlwin yes you should always check before proceeding into form processing

Comment: @Ghost But isn't this important especially now in the morning when there is soooo much dupe (crap) questions ?!

Comment: @Rizier123 yeah, its like never ending :D

Answer (score -1):

$_POST['pass'] should be $_POST['password'] as same as you named that field

Comment: OP doesn't have `$_pass` in his code

Comment: The field is named "pass", "password" is the type ...